# How do we construct a product of projective spaces as a sequence of projective bundles?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Sometimes, it is useful to treat a variety as a projective bundle over a projective space. Therefore, I would like to understand several examples below.

For example, the product variety $\mathbf{P}^1\times \mathbf{P}^2$ is isomorphic to the projective bundle
$$\mathbf{P}(\mathcal{O}(-a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(-a) )\to \mathbf{P}^2.$$

The product variety $\mathbf{P}^2\times \mathbf{P}^2$ is isomorphic to the projective bundle
$$\mathbf{P}(\mathcal{O}(-b)\oplus \mathcal{O}(-b)\oplus \mathcal{O}(-b) )\to \mathbf{P}^2.$$

I would like to know why those varieties are isomorphic (rigorous proof and how to see this intuitively).

Moreover, I would like to know if this is true in general, that is,
for $\mathbf{P}^{n_1}\times\cdots \times \mathbf{P}^{n_r}$, is there a projective bundle structure like the above examples?

Any references and answers are welcome!

Comment: What is $\mathcal{O}(-a)$? A product $\prod \mathbf{P}^{n_i}$ is trivially a projective bundle over the product with the $i$th factor removed. Namely, it’s the projective bundle associated to a trivial vector bundle of rank $n_i+1$.

Comment: @leibnewtz Here $\mathcal{O}(-a)$ is the twisted sheaf of the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}$ over $\mathbf{P}^2$ by some integer $-a$. I agree with what you said. But is there a projective bundle structure over a single projective space, say $\mathbf{P}^n$, instead of the product of projective spaces?

Comment: I don’t see why you’d expect this to be true. You’d in particular need to find a map from this product to some projective space whose fibers are all projective spaces of the same dimension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question:** For example, the product variety $\mathbf{P}^1\times \mathbf{P}^2$ is isomorphic to the projective bundle
$$\mathbf{P}(\mathcal{O}(-a)\oplus \mathcal{O}(-a) )\to \mathbf{P}^2.$$

The product variety $\mathbf{P}^2\times \mathbf{P}^2$ is isomorphic to the projective bundle
$$\mathbf{P}(\mathcal{O}(-b)\oplus \mathcal{O}(-b)\oplus \mathcal{O}(-b) )\to \mathbf{P}^2.$$

I would like to know why those varieties are isomorphic (rigorous proof and how to see this intuitively).

**Answer:** Let $C$ be the projective line and $S$ the projective plane and let $L(d):=\mathcal{O}_C(d), M(d):=\mathcal{O}_S(d)$.

In the first case you get isomorphisms

$$ \mathbb{P}((L(-a)\oplus L(-a))^*) \cong \mathbb{P}((L(-a)\otimes(\mathcal{O}_S^2))^*) \cong \mathbb{P}((\mathcal{O}_S^2)^*) \cong S \times C.$$

This is because for any locally trivial finite rank sheaf $E$ it follows

$$\mathbb{P}((L(d)\otimes E)^*) \cong \mathbb{P}(E^*)$$

and the fact that for a trivial vector bundle $E:=\mathcal{O}_S^{r+1}$ it follows

$$Proj(E^*) \cong \mathbb{P}^r_S \cong \mathbb{P}^r \times \mathbb{P}^2.$$

When you twist $E$ with an invertible sheaf $L(d)$, you get isomorphisms (see Hartshorne Ex.II.7.10). A similar proof shows the second case.

**Question:** Moreover, I would like to know if this is true in general, that is, for $\mathbf{P}^{n_1}\times\cdots \times \mathbf{P}^{n_r}$, is there a projective bundle structure like the above examples?
Any references and answers are welcome!"

**Answer:** Use induction as follows: Let $Y:=\mathbb{P}^{n_1}\times \cdots \times \mathbb{P}^{n_l}:=X\times \mathbb{P}^{n_l}$. Let $E_l:=\mathcal{O}_X^{n_l+1}$. It follows

$$\mathbb{P}(E_l^*) \cong X \times \mathbb{P}^{n_l} \cong Y.$$

Hence you can construct any finite product $Y:=\prod \mathbb{P}^{n_i}$ as a sequence of projective bundles.

**Example:** If $l=3$ and $Y:=\mathbb{P}^{n_1} \times \mathbb{P}^{n_2}\times \mathbb{P}^{n_3}$ and if you fix the projection map

$$\pi_1: Y \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n_1}$$
with fiber $F:=\mathbb{P}^{n_2}\times \mathbb{P}^{n_3}$, the fiber is trivially not isomorphic to projective space. There is by the above argument a sequence of maps

$$Y\cong \mathbb{P}(E_2^*) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(E_1^*) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n_1}$$

with $E_i$ a locally trivial sheaf for $i=1,2$.

**Application:** You may use the "projective bundle formula" and an induction to calculate the Chow ring (or Grothendieck ring) of any finite product of projective spaces: The formula says

$$CH^*(\mathbb{P}(E^*)) \cong CH^*(X)[t]/(t^{e})$$

where $e:=rk(E)$ (Hartshorne, CH.AppendixA.3).